# Why is my two-way WPF binding becoming detached?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

My two-way binding to a toggle button gets detached after the initial value is set to true.  When I untoggle the button it is no longer bound.

I have two toggle buttons:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="BackupButton" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" DataContext="{Binding BackupVM}" IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsViewVisible}">Backup</RadioButton>
<RadioButton x:Name="RestoreButton" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">Restore</RadioButton>
```

My property in the BackupViewModel (instanced as BackupVM) that I wish to bind to:

```
private bool _IsViewVisible = true;
public bool IsViewVisible
{
        get { return _IsViewVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _IsViewVisible)
            {
                _IsViewVisible = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsViewVisible"));
            }
        }
    }
```

When one is toggled on I display a specific user control (view) and hide the other. What I need to do is tell my underlying viewmodel that the view is hidden so I can stop a timer that refreshes some data. After the IsChecked value is set on load the binding gets detached for some reason.  Here is the output after running a trace:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 52 : Created BindingExpression (hash=9343812) for Binding (hash=58368655)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 :   Path: 'IsViewVisible'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 57 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Attach to         System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton.IsChecked (hash=17818390)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Found data context element: RadioButton (hash=17818390) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Activate with root item <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812):   Item at level 0 is null - no accessor
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): TransferValue - using fallback/default value 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): TransferValue - using final value 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 92 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Got PropertyChanged event from RadioButton (hash=17818390) for DataContext
System.Windows.Data Warning: 75 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Deactivate
System.Windows.Data Warning: 99 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Activate with root item BackupViewModel (hash=58266349)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812):   At level 0 - for BackupViewModel.IsViewVisible found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsViewVisible)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Replace item at level 0 with BackupViewModel (hash=58266349), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsViewVisible)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 97 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): GetValue at level 0 from BackupViewModel (hash=58266349) using RuntimePropertyInfo(IsViewVisible): 'True'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): TransferValue - got raw value 'True'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): TransferValue - using final value 'True'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 75 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Deactivate
System.Windows.Data Warning: 99 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=9343812): Detach
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure its really not "bound"?  I've had it happen to me too and looks like its missing in yours...  You have nothing indicating

NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true

in your {binding Mode.... } content

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work either. I know it is bound on load because I can verify the getter is called in the debugger.  But when I click the other button the setter is never called.

Comment: @JRadness, yes, you are correct, it will bind on the first time via the "Getter" when debugging.  However, you need to tell the control... In addition to the first time you are started, I want the OTHER SIDE of this binding to tell me when it changes so I can get updated again.  That is what the "NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true" is for.. Don't have VS2010 in front of me, but there are a couple other parts of the binding that are needed similar to it you might need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a syntax thing... it doesn't appear to be binding to your `ViewModel` at all. Try this:

```
<RadioButton Grid.Row="0" x:Name="BackupButton" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" IsChecked="{Binding IsViewVisible, Mode=TwoWay}">
    Backup
    <RadioButton.DataContext>
        <local:BackupVM />
    </RadioButton.DataContext>
</RadioButton>
```

Where you define the `local namespace` as:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Note: Replace `WpfApplication1` with the name of your namespace.

Comment: I am binding to my viewmodel.  This window has a data context that contains and instance of my BackupViewModel name BackupVM.  So I added DataContext="{Binding BackupVM}".

Comment: @JRadness: Are there any parent controls of your radio button that also have their `DataContext` set?

Comment: @JRadness or anything in your code-behind that changes the `DataContext` of the radio buttons or any parents at run time? If not, then try removing the `DataContext` from your `RadioButton`... it should inherit from the parent `DataContext`.

Comment: Even if I move the property to which I want to bind to the main datacontext, I get the same behavior.

Comment: @JRadness I literally took your code as is and removed the text `DataContext="{Binding BackupVM}"` from the first radio button and it started working. As soon as I put it back in, it stops working. I also have my Window `DataContext` set to `BackupVM`.